# Orbeon sending instance data to a web service

Tags: web-services, orbeon, xforms

I created an instance for the web service call and response.

```
<xf:instance id="ws-request-instance">                         
                            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.estat.zzi.si/">
                               <soapenv:Header/>
                               <soapenv:Body>
                                  <ws:orbeonGet>
                                     <dokumentId/>
                                     <type/>
                                     <formData/>
                                  </ws:orbeonGet>
                               </soapenv:Body>
                            </soapenv:Envelope>
</xf:instance>

<xf:instance id="ws-response-instance">                       
                            <soapenv:Envelope>
                            </soapenv:Envelope>
</xf:instance>
```

The submit function calls the created service like this:

```
<xf:submission id="submit" action="http://was7test.zzi.si:8081/EStat-RO-WS-91-XX/orbeon" method="post" ref="instance('ws-request-instance')" replace="instance" mediatype="application/soap+xml" instance="ws-response-instance">
                <xf:message ev:event="xforms-submit-done" level="modal">Done Result:<xf:output value="instance('ws-response-instance')"/>
                <xf:output value="event('error-type')"/>; Status: <xf:output value="event('response-status-code')"/>; URI: <xf:output value="event('resource-uri')"/>; Headers: <xf:output value="event('response-headers')"/>; Body: <xf:output value="event('response-body')"/>
                </xf:message>

                <xf:message ev:event="xforms-submit-error" level="modal">
                A submission error occurred: <xf:output value="event('error-type')"/>; Status: <xf:output value="event('response-status-code')"/>; URI: <xf:output value="event('resource-uri')"/>; Headers: <xf:output value="event('response-headers')"/>; Body: <xf:output value="event('response-body')"/>
                </xf:message>
            </xf:submission>
```

When the submit button is clicked we fill in the parameters to the web service call like this:

```
<xf:action ev:event="submit-form">
            <xf:setvalue ref="instance('ws-request-instance')//type" value="xxf:get-request-parameter('type')"/>
            <xf:setvalue ref="instance('ws-request-instance')//dokumentId" value="xxf:get-request-parameter('documentId')"/>
            <xf:setvalue ref="instance('ws-request-instance')//formData" value="instance('fr-form-instance')"/>
            <xf:send submission="submit"/>
</xf:action>
```

In the formData parameter I would like to get the "XML" data of the fr-form-instance. For example, the instance is "X", and I am only getting X, not the whole "instance" in XML.

Is this even posible? Can you please guide me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Found out how ;) I just used "saxon" and wrote:

```
<xf:setvalue
    ref="instance('ws-request-instance-get')//formData"
    value="saxon:serialize(instance('fr-form-instance'), 'xml')"/>
```